# Swift Images place in wrong cell and keep chaging in UICollectionview

Tags: swift, swift3, uiimageview, uicollectionview

I have searched but I was not successful to find the answer to my question, I am downloading images from internet and put them into collection view but when I scroll the places are changing even without scrolling they places on the wrong cell here is my code :

```
  override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)

    var Label = cell.viewWithTag(2) as! UILabel
    Label.text = namesArray[indexPath.row]

    var image = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UIImageView
    let URLString = imgLink[indexPath.row]
    let imgUrl = URL(string: URLString)

    image.downloadedFrom(url: imgUrl!, contentMode: UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFit)
    UIimg.insert(image.image!, at: indexPath.row)
    return cell
}


public extension UIImageView {
    func downloadedFrom(url: URL, contentMode mode: UIViewContentMode = .scaleAspectFit) {
        contentMode = mode
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            guard
                let httpURLResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpURLResponse.statusCode == 200,
                let mimeType = response?.mimeType, mimeType.hasPrefix("image"),
                let data = data, error == nil,
                let image = UIImage(data: data)
                else { return }
            DispatchQueue.main.async() { () -> Void in
                self.image = image
            }
            }.resume()
    }
    func downloadedFrom(link: String, contentMode mode: UIViewContentMode = .scaleAspectFit) {
        guard let url = URL(string: link) else { return }
        downloadedFrom(url: url, contentMode: mode)
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)


var image1 = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UIImageView
    let URLString = imgLink[indexPath.row]
    let imgUrl = URL(string: URLString)


    var Label = cell.viewWithTag(2) as! UILabel
    Label.text = namesArray[indexPath.row]

    getImage(urlString: URLString) { (success:Bool, data:NSData?, errorDescription:String?) in
        if success {

            DispatchQueue.main.async() {
                let image = UIImage(data: data! as Data)
                image1.image = image

            }
        }
    }
   return cell
}





func getImage(urlString:String, completionHandler:@escaping (_ success:Bool, _ data:NSData?, _ errorDescription:String?) -> Void) -> Void {

    let url = NSURL(string: urlString)
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url! as URL)
     let session = URLSession.shared
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { (data, response, error) in

        guard let data = data, error == nil else {
            completionHandler(false,nil, error?.localizedDescription)
            return
        }

        completionHandler(true, data as NSData?, nil)
    }

    task.resume()

}
```

Comment: You need to look into cell reuse.  You set the image view on a cell to a particular image and then when you scroll that cell gets reused so now has the incorrect image.  Keep your data (images) separate from the UI (cells) and just refresh the cells from the data.

Comment: Cell for row at indexpath code is correct. you just need to download image into background thread. https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage use this library. It will load image in background and also cache your image.
ex : image.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: NSURL, placeholderImage: UIImage(named: ""))

Comment: I dont need to use library for downloading images

Answer (score 1):

This function is an asynchronous function which will take some time to complete

```
image.downloadedFrom(url: imgUrl!, contentMode: UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFit)
```

So this line..

```
UIimg.insert(image.image!, at: indexPath.row)
```

Will run ***before*** the above function call has finished downloading the image. This will be causing your issue.

Your `downloadedFrom` function should use a completion handler to run some code after the image has downloaded for it to work properly.

I usually use a function like the one below for fetching images

```
func getImage(urlString:String, completionHandler:(success:Bool, data:NSData?, errorDescription:String?) -> Void) -> Void {

        let url = NSURL(string: urlString)
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)

        let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) { (data, response, error) in

            guard let data = data where error == nil else {
                completionHandler(success: false,data: nil, errorDescription: error?.localizedDescription)
                return
            }

            completionHandler(success: true, data: data, errorDescription: nil)
        }

        task.resume()

}
```

Which can be used in a tableCell/collectionCell like this:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let photo = fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! Photo
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! AlbumCell

        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
        cell.imageView.image = UIImage(named: "placeholder")

        if let image = photo.image {
            cell.imageView.image = image
        } else {

            VTClient.sharedInstance().getImage(photo.url) { (success:Bool, data:NSData?, errorDescription:String?) in
                if success {

                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                        let image = UIImage(data: data!)
                        cell.imageView.image = image
                        FlickrClient.Caches.imageCache.storeImage(image, withIdentifier: photo.id)
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return cell
    }
}
```

See my project here https://github.com/martinjkelly/virtual-tourist/blob/master/Virtual Tourist for more information on how this is used

Comment: use `let session = URLSesssion.shared`. This code is an older project, Swift 2 I think, may need some slight changes

Comment: Sorry I should of explained a bit better. This is from a project I worked on when learning iOS, you don't need those classes. VTClient is just where I put the getImage function, you can put it anywhere. These classes are specific to my project. Photo class is just a data class and FlickrClient fetches image data from Flickr API. I use an image cache in that class to store images for faster loading. You don't have to do this but it would help with performance. You would need to use the parts of my code that you need if you want to use it. I just shown my code to show how it would be done

Comment: you dont have photo class, you dont need that part. show your updated code

Comment: The code looks like it should be ok now, what issue are you getting now?

Comment: user this code: `var image = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UIImageView
    let URLString = imgLink[indexPath.row]
    let imgUrl = URL(string: URLString)` can you add `print(indexPath.row, URLString)` and see what gets output to the console

Comment: are the cells themselves in the wrong order, or the images?. Do the labels match the images?

Comment: I'm a bit confused now as to the problem. labels and images are matching in the collection view, cells are in the right order, but the images aren't in the right order?

Comment: YES it is the problem

Comment: can you screenshot collectionView?